# Trouble Navigating between pages windows 8.1- javascript

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to navigate between pages in windows 8.1 using HTML/JS.  I can navigate between the home screen and the vehicle screen and back, and I can also navigate between the home screen and the part screen and back.  I cannot navigate from the vehicle screen to the part screen and vice versa.  Also, if I go from home to vehicle to home, I can't go to the part screen.  I am using buttons to do the navigating...

**Home Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Home Page</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1/js/ui.js"></script>

<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/pages/home/home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/pages/home/home.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
<div class="fragment homepage">        
    <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
        <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
            <div class="pagetitle">Vehicle Inventory</div>
        </h1>
    </header>
    <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
        <h3 class="pageDesc">Choose Item to Add/Update/Delete</h3>
        <div class="option-btn-home">
            <button class="normal-btn-home" id="vehicle-btn">Vehicle</button>
            <button class="normal-btn-home" id="part-btn">Part</button>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Vehicle and PAge screens are similar to the home page html.

**Home page js:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        //navigates to vehicle page
        document.getElementById('vehicle-btn').onclick = function (event) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/vehicle/vehicle.html");
        }
        //navigates to part page
        document.getElementById('part-btn').onclick = function (event) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/part/part.html");
        }
    }
});
})();
```

**Vehicle Screen js:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/vehicle/vehicle.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        //navigates to home page
        document.getElementById('home-btn').onclick = function (event) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/home/home.html");
        }
        //navigates to part page
        document.getElementById('part-btn').onclick = function (event) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/part/part.html");
        }
    }
});
})();
```

**Part screen js:**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/part/part.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        //navigates to home page
        document.getElementById('home-btn').onclick = function (event) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/home/home.html");
        }
        //navigates to vehicle page
        document.getElementById('vehicle-btn').onclick = function (event) {
            WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/vehicle/vehicle.html");
        }
    }
});
})();
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it, but I'm not sure why it works now.  This is my new javascript code:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {
        var vehiclebtn = element.querySelector("#vehicle-btn");
        vehiclebtn.addEventListener("click", this.toVehicle, false);
        var partbtn = element.querySelector("#part-btn");
        partbtn.addEventListener("click", this.toPart, false);
    },

    toVehicle: function(mouseEvent) {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/vehicle/vehicle.html");
    },
    toPart: function(mouseEvent) {
        WinJS.Navigation.navigate("/pages/part/part.html");
    }
});    
})();
```